# My view record by course is not working properly

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, switch-statement

I need help with my program which is not yet finished. I think there is a problem with my coding on `searchArray(String key)` method.

My Main Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentArray {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Student[] stud = new Student[100];
    static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (true) {
            int select;
            System.out.println("1. Add Student Record");
            System.out.println("2. View Student Record");
            System.out.println("3. Update Student Record");
            System.out.println("4. Delete Student Record");
            System.out.println("0. Exit");
            select = sc.nextInt();

            switch (select) {
                case 1:
                    addStud();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    viewStud();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 0:
                    return;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Option");
            }
        }

    }

    public static void addStud() {
        int numID, year;
        String userName, course;

        int addMore;

        do {

            System.out.println("1. Enter Student ID: ");
            numID = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("2. Enter Student Name");
            userName = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("3. Enter Student Course");
            course = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("4. Enter Student Year");
            year = sc.nextInt();
            stud[count] = new Student(numID, year, userName, course);
            ++count;

            System.out.println("To add another Student Record Press 1");
            addMore = sc.nextInt();
        } while (addMore == 1);

    }

    public static void viewStud() {

        int select;

        System.out.println("1. View Record by ID number: " );
        System.out.println("2. View Record by Course: " );
        System.out.println("3. View Record by Course and Year: " );
        System.out.println("4. View All: " );
        select = sc.nextInt();

        while (select < 1 || select > 4){
            System.out.println("Please enter values 1-4 only: ");
            select = sc.nextInt();
        }

        switch (select){

            case 1:
                int view1;
                System.out.println("Please enter Student ID Number: ");
                view1 = sc.nextInt();
                sc.nextLine();
                searchArray(view1);
                break;
            case 2:
                String view2;
                System.out.println("Please enter Student Course: ");
                view2 = sc.nextLine();
                searchArray(view2);
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                for (Student element : stud) {
                    if (null != element) {
                        System.out.println("1. Student ID: " + element.getNumID());
                        System.out.println("2. Student Name: " + element.getUserName());
                        System.out.println("3. Student Course: " + element.getCourse());
                        System.out.println("4. Student Year: " + element.getYear() + "\n");
                    }
                }
                break;

        }


    }
    public static void searchArray(int key){
        boolean isExist = false;
        int temp = 0;

        for(int x = 0; x < count; ++x){
            if(key == stud[x].getNumID()){
                temp = x;
                isExist = true;
                break;
            }

        }

        if(isExist){
            System.out.println("1. Student ID: " + stud[temp].getNumID());
            System.out.println("2. Student Name: " + stud[temp].getUserName());
            System.out.println("3. Student Course: " + stud[temp].getCourse());
            System.out.println("4. Student Year: " + stud[temp].getYear() +"\n");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("The Student ID: " +key+ " is invalid");

    }
    public static void searchArray(String key){
        boolean isExist = false;

        for(int x = 0; x < count; ++x){
            if(key.equalsIgnoreCase(stud[x].getCourse())){
                System.out.println("1. Student ID: " + stud[x].getNumID());
                System.out.println("2. Student Name: " + stud[x].getUserName());
                System.out.println("3. Student Course: " + stud[x].getCourse());
                System.out.println("4. Student Year: " + stud[x].getYear() +"\n");
                isExist = true;
            }

        }

        if(isExist == false){
            System.out.println("The Student ID: " +key+ " is invalid");
        }

    }

}
```

My Student Class:

```
public class Student {

    private int numID, year;
    private String userName, course;

    public Student(int numID, int year, String userName, String course) {

        this.numID = numID;
        this.year = year;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.course = course;

    }


    public int getNumID() {
        return numID;
    }

    public void setNumID(int numID) {
        this.numID = numID;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

}
```

Error when asked Please enter Student Course: it will always show The Student ID:  is invalid

Comment: Did you try debugging your code and check what is the value of variables when you get the "error". If you didn't it is a great moment to learn how debugger works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just replace case 2 of your viewStud() with this:

```
case 2:
            String view2;
            System.out.println("Please enter Student Course: ");
            sc.nextLine();//to remove residual '\n' from sc!!               
            view2 = sc.nextLine();
            searchArray(view2);
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten multiple (5 by my count) calls to `sc.nextLine()`; after `sc.nextInt()`. Adding these will fix your issue.

Without consuming newline your menu tries to read in the next int and is unhappy because "\n" is not an int.

Comment: thanks, i only know that i have to call sc.nextLine() after sc.nextInt() if the previous input was a string sc.nextLine(). I didn't know that the same applies to case.